# How to find the lowest cost of partition (A,B) in a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Given a complete graph $G=(V,E)$. The "intracost" of $A\subset V(G)$ is defined by the total weight of all edges with both ends in $A$.

Given a complete graph $G=(V,E)$,  where $|V(G)|=100$. Every edge has nonzero weight. Find a partition $(A,B)$ such that $|A|=|B|=50$ and the sum of intracost of $A$ and the intracost of $B$ is minimum.

I tried to start with finding a minimum cost perfect matching, but have no idea what to do next.

Comment: This seems to be a hard question. I would question the restriction that every edge has nonzero weight. It seems irrelevant as I can increase all the edge weights by a certain amount and the minimal construction will still be valid.

Comment: intracost $A$ + intracost $B$ + intercost $(A,B) = \sum_{e \in E} W(e)$